# URL parsing in Python - normalizing double-slash in paths

Tags: python, urlparse

I am working on an app which needs to parse URLs (mostly HTTP URLs) in HTML pages - I have no control over the input and some of it is, as expected, a bit messy.

One problem I'm encountering frequently is that urlparse is very strict (and possibly even buggy?) when it comes to parsing and joining URLs that have double-slashes in the path part, for example:

```
testUrl = 'http://www.example.com//path?foo=bar'
urlparse.urljoin(testUrl, 
                 urlparse.urlparse(testUrl).path)
```

Instead of the expected result `http://www.example.com//path` (or even better, with a normalized single slash), I end up with `http://path`.

BTW the reason I'm running such code is because it's the only way I found so far to strip the query / fragment part off of URLs. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but I couldn't find one.

Can anyone recommend a way to avoid this, or should I just normalize the path myself using a (relatively simple, I know) regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's the only way to strip the query / fragment part"? What does the slash have to do with the query?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the query - the reason I'm parsing a URL and then joining it's own path back into it is because I want to strip out the query and fragment. If there was a better way to do it, I wouldn't need to solve this problem

Comment: I think urlparse is just implementing the RFC of URLs correctly - that specifies that after the <hostname>:<port> part seems to be only one slash (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) - so in your case I would try to strip the extra slash before passing it to urlparse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to get the url without the query part, I would skip the urlparse module and just do:

```
testUrl.rsplit('?')
```

The url will be at index 0 of the list returned and the query at index 1.

It is not possible to have two '?' in an url so it should work for all urls.

Comment: This does not answer any urlparse issues, but it definitely solves my use case in a very simple way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The path (`//path`) alone is not valid, which confuses the function and gets interpreted as a hostname

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3.3

> If a URI does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin with two slash characters ("//").

I don't particularly like either of these solutions, but they work:

```
import re
import urlparse

testurl = 'http://www.example.com//path?foo=bar'

parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(testurl))
parsed[2] = re.sub("/{2,}", "/", parsed[2]) # replace two or more / with one
cleaned = urlparse.urlunparse(parsed)

print cleaned
# http://www.example.com/path?foo=bar

print urlparse.urljoin(
    testurl, 
    urlparse.urlparse(cleaned).path)

# http://www.example.com//path
```

Depending on what you are doing, you could do the joining manually:

```
import re
import urlparse

testurl = 'http://www.example.com//path?foo=bar'
parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(testurl))

newurl = ["" for i in range(6)] # could urlparse another address instead

# Copy first 3 values from
# ['http', 'www.example.com', '//path', '', 'foo=bar', '']
for i in range(3):
    newurl[i] = parsed[i]
    
# Rest are blank
for i in range(4, 6):
    newurl[i] = ''

print urlparse.urlunparse(newurl)
# http://www.example.com//path
```

Comment: The URL is in fact valid, because **it does** contain an authority section - so the URL may begin with '//'. In any case even if it is not being able to parse invalid but "real world" URLs could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in [official urlparse docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) that:

> If url is an absolute URL (that is, starting with // or scheme://), the url‘s host name and/or scheme will be present in the result. For example

```
urljoin('http://www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/Python.html',
...         '//www.python.org/%7Eguido')
'http://www.python.org/%7Eguido'
```

> If you do not want that behavior, preprocess the url with urlsplit() and urlunsplit(), removing possible scheme and netloc parts.

So you can do :

```
urlparse.urljoin(testUrl,
             urlparse.urlparse(testUrl).path.replace('//','/'))
```

Output = `'http://www.example.com/path'`

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
def http_normalize_slashes(url):
    url = str(url)
    segments = url.split('/')
    correct_segments = []
    for segment in segments:
        if segment != '':
            correct_segments.append(segment)
    first_segment = str(correct_segments[0])
    if first_segment.find('http') == -1:
        correct_segments = ['http:'] + correct_segments
    correct_segments[0] = correct_segments[0] + '/'
    normalized_url = '/'.join(correct_segments)
    return normalized_url
```

Example URLs:

```
print(http_normalize_slashes('http://www.example.com//path?foo=bar'))
print(http_normalize_slashes('http:/www.example.com//path?foo=bar'))
print(http_normalize_slashes('www.example.com//x///c//v///path?foo=bar'))
print(http_normalize_slashes('http://////www.example.com//x///c//v///path?foo=bar'))
```

Will return:

```
http://www.example.com/path?foo=bar
http://www.example.com/path?foo=bar
http://www.example.com/x/c/v/path?foo=bar
http://www.example.com/x/c/v/path?foo=bar
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl), try:

```
import furl

f = furl.furl('http://www.example.com//path?foo=bar')
f.set(path=f.path.normalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not that be a solution?

```
urlparse.urlparse(testUrl).path.replace('//', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175421/joining-strings-to-form-a-url#175423/) seemed to give the best results in the cases I tried for correcting double slashes in paths, without touching the initial double slash in the http:// bit.

here's the code:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from functools import reduce


def slash_join(*args):
    return reduce(urljoin, args).rstrip("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

i've adopted to my needs @yunhasnawa's answer. here is part:

```
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

def sanitize_url(url):
    url_parsed = urlparse(url)  
    return urlunparse((url_parsed.scheme, url_parsed.netloc, avoid_double_slash(url_parsed.path), '', '', ''))

def avoid_double_slash(path):
  parts = path.split('/')
  not_empties = [part for part in parts if part]
  return '/'.join(not_empties)


>>> sanitize_url('https://hostname.doma.in:8443/complex-path////next//')
'https://hostname.doma.in:8443/complex-path/next'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be totally safe, but you could use this regex:

```
import re


def sanitize_url(url: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r"([^:]/)(/)+", r"\1", url)
```

It will replace "[not colon] followed by **2** slashes" by the "[not colon] followed by a **single** slash". The [not colon] is used to preserve the http:// or https://.