# Passing URL query strings into a function to be added

Tags: python

How would I go about grabbing the values from the URL, a and b, then passing them to the add function? The result should come out to be: `{"c": x}`, where x is the sum of a and b.

The code:

```
op = 'add'
a = random.randint(0,10)
b = random.randint(0,10)
/%s?a=%s&b=%s' % (op, a, b)

result = res.json()

if op=='add':
    assert a+b == result['c']
```

The function:

```
def add():
    import json
    return json.dumps({'c': ???})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL parsing in Python - normalizing double-slash in paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925938/url-parsing-in-python-normalizing-double-slash-in-paths)

Comment: Not at all, @Serdmanczyk, since the user doesn't even know about `urlparse`, apparently...

Comment: Sorry, was trying to find a decent duplicate answer and accidentally hit enter on the wrong one.  Is there a way to take back flags?  Answer below makes sense.

Comment: This might be a good time to look through meta.stackoverflow.com for posts like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the overwhelming response! Your comments are appreciated, but none were what I was looking for. I filtered out a lot of the codes, so I guess my question altered. I just edit my question.. This should make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), a standard library module designed for tasks like these!

> **urlparse.parse_qs(qs[, keep_blank_values[, strict_parsing]])**
>
> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary.
>   The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values
>   are lists of values for each name.
>
> The optional argument keep_blank_values is a flag indicating whether
>   blank values in percent-encoded queries should be treated as blank
>   strings. A true value indicates that blanks should be retained as
>   blank strings. The default false value indicates that blank values are
>   to be ignored and treated as if they were not included.
>
> The optional argument strict_parsing is a flag indicating what to do
>   with parsing errors. If false (the default), errors are silently
>   ignored. If true, errors raise a ValueError exception.

Example:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('a=1&b=1') # raw query string
{'a': ['1'], 'b': ['1']}
```

Note that you can parse an entire URL into its components (including a query string) using other functions in `urlparse` as well.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this can be used? If you feel this might be a sort of "do my homework for me" question, feel free to point it out, but answering should be done properly as well.

Comment: @icedwater I was in the process of adding an example right as you commented. :)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a good hint without giving the answer outright.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse
import json

def add(a, b):
    return json.dumps({'c': a+b})

url = 'add?a=1&b=1'

q_dict = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query, keep_blank_values=True)
# q_dict = {'a': ['1'], 'b': ['1']}

print add(a=q_dict['a'][0], b=q_dict['b'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve my problem! I appreciate all the help, but none of the solutions provided here applied to my question. This is entirely my fault because I worded the question totally different.